# Efficient way to find a group that contains an exact list of members

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

My app has a Group model that has a members property which contains a list of member keys. I would like to find groups that contain an exact list of members. I'm trying to find an efficient way to do this. The method I have below works, but is slow, particularly due to the loop in the function. Are there better ways to do this? Should I be modeling this differently?

Here's my Group model.

```
class Group(ndb.Model):
    members = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User', repeated=True)
```

Here's the function to find the group that contains a set of members.

```
def get_group_with_members(members):
    groups_for_one_member = Group.query(Group.members == members[0].key)

    # Get list of member keys.
    member_keys = [member.key for member in members]

    # Loop through groups of one member to see if any groups contain all the members.
    for group in groups_for_one_member:
        if set(group.members) == set(member_keys):
            return group
    return None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could concatenate a sorted list of the member IDs and store that as a property of your group. Constructing the filter value in the same way when you query will allow you to return just the groups that match entirely. If the length of your member-lists, or the length of your user-IDs, means these concatenated values will be too long for a StringProperty, then you could hash the values.

Comment: And use a ComputedProperty, so you don't have to explicitly manage this property.

Comment: Only problem is this won't scale if total lenght of keys of members of the group starts hits 1MB.